# SafeCopy worked but I have a few problems

Tags: data-recovery, gparted, safecopy

I had a 60G NTFS drive that had 28 physically bad blocks as reported by GParted. I used SafeCopy to recover to the root of an empty 500G drive using SafeCopy defaults. Everything worked as expected and I can access the data fine, but now the 500G drive has a couple of issues.

1. The bad blocks, which I guess SafeCopy filled with zeroes or whatever, are apparently still marked as bad on the 500G drive that I copied to, preventing GParted and numerous other programs from being able to work with it.
2. The 500G drive now shows the remaining free space to be the same as the 60G drive that I copied from instead of the 400G+ that it should show. I can't get access through GParted to see if I can fix this because GParted says that the drive has 28 physical errors and it won't mount it. I thought I might be able to make a backup image and restore it back to the drive but the backup software that I use, Acronis, shows that the image file would be 500G instead of the less than 60G of actual data.

This drive is being used as a Windows non-system drive. Windows Explorer shows the drive as 60G but when you go into Disk Management the top pane shows 60G while the bottom pane shows a graphical image of a 500G primary partition. Since this is a non-system disk I realize that I could simply just transfer all the files over to another properly partitioned and formatted disk but for future reference I would like to know how to avoid or fix this.

Is this normal behavior for a SafeCopy transfer? Did I make a mistake in using the SafeCopy defaults?